# Query is putting the result into the row below the formula—how to put in the same cell as the formula?

Tags: google-sheets

I've used this query function to sum data based on conditions from another sheet:

```
=QUERY(Backlinking!A2:Z1000, "Select Sum(R) where F='performance management tools'")
```

It returns the correct sum:

[image]

but the result is in the cell UNDERNEATH the cell I want to see it in.

How do I make the Query result display in the same cell as the formula?

Answer (score 1):

Query returns result with column name
Use this formula if you need only value in that cell

```
QUERY(Backlinking!A2:Z1000, "Select SUM(R) where F='performance management tools' label SUM(R) ''"))
```

or

```
=SUM(QUERY(Backlinking!A2:Z1000, "Select R where F='performance management tools'"))
```

In this case simple SUMIFS would be enough

```
=SUMIFS(Backlinking!R2:R1000,Backlinking!F2:F1000,"performance management tools")
```